# convert subquery to a join in jpql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes ClassA and ClassB. Many ClassB's can have association with a single ClassA, hence a many-to-one relationship from ClassB to ClassA. Relationship is  like:

```
ClassA {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ClassB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private ClassB classB = new ClassB();
}
```

I have a query like this:

```
delete from ClassA as a 
where a.classB in (select b from ClassB as b where b.attr1=?1 and b.attr2=?2)
and a.attr3=?3
```

And i converted this query like:

```
delete from ClassA as a join a.classb as b where b.attr1=?1 and b.attr2=?2
and a.attr3=?3"
```

When i run this i get below exception :

> ```
> ERROR PARSER    - line 1:28: unexpected token: join
>
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
> ```
>
> node to traverse cannot be null!;
>   nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   node to traverse cannot be null!

Can anybody help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot DELETE from a JOIN. Why did you want to rewrite the DELETE statement anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase it like this: no JOIN can be used in a bulk query. From the official documentation:

> #### [13.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)
>
> As already discussed, automatic and
>   transparent object/relational mapping
>   is concerned with the management of
>   the object state. The object state is
>   available in memory. This means that
>   manipulating data directly in the
>   database (using the SQL Data
>   Manipulation Language (DML) the
>   statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
>   will not affect in-memory state.
>   However, Hibernate provides methods
>   for bulk SQL-style DML statement
>   execution that is performed through
>   the Hibernate Query Language (HQL).
>
> The pseudo-syntax for UPDATE and
>   DELETE statements is: `( UPDATE |
>   DELETE ) FROM? EntityName (WHERE
>   where_conditions)?`.
>
> Some points to note:
>
> - In the from-clause, the `FROM` keyword is optional
> - There can only be a single entity named in the from-clause. It can,
>     however, be aliased. If the entity
>     name is aliased, then any property
>     references must be qualified using
>     that alias. If the entity name is not
>     aliased, then it is illegal for any
>     property references to be qualified.
> - **No [joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms), either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk
>     HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in
>     the where-clause, where the subqueries
>     themselves may contain joins.**
> - The where clause is also optional.

So what you currently have (using a sub-query) is optimal and there is no reason to rewrite it.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [13.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)